# Security Admin role not visible in ServiceNow

Tags: servicenow

I can't assign yourself the security_admin role (or assign it to anyone else unless you already have the role). If I look at the sys_user_role table and search for security_admin without having the role, you'll get a security error.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow security_admin role is not visible to admins in Helsinki and Istanbul (Strange) . You can try below script to assign yourself security_admin privileges

```
var sr = new GlideRecord("sys_user_role");  
     sr.addQuery("name","security_admin");   
     sr.query();   
      if (sr.next())   
     {  
        var hh = new GlideRecord("sys_user_has_role");   
        hh.initialize();   
        hh.user = gs.getUserID();  
        hh.role = sr.sys_id;  
        hh.insert();   
      }
```

Comment: Thank you.It helped

Answer (score 0):

This is intentional as of the Helsinki release.  In the past, a normal Admin could elevate their own privileges to the Security Admin, which is not always desirable. Just as no user should be able to elevate their own access, nor should an Admin be able to elevate their own access. This is why only someone with Security Admin access can grant the same access to another person.